# How to edit the parameter in the decorator dynamically in the runtime in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming, python-decorators, telethon

can anyone help me to make the "FROM" variable dynamic in the decorator in the runtime?

The script is a message forwarder, in the beginning it is working with the Chat IDs I provide in FROM list. Then When I want to update with the handler() function I can not add a new Chat ID into FROM list in the decorator because the script is running already.

Can someone give me a hand?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.sessions import StringSession

telethon_client = TelegramClient(StringSession(SESSION), APP_ID, API_HASH)
telethon_client.start()
# some code here

FROM=[CHAT_ID_1, CHAT_ID_2, CHAT_ID_3]

@telethon_client.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing=outgoing, incoming=True, chats=FROM))
async def catch_messages(event):
    global FROM
    # some codes here
    await telethon_client.send_message(entity=TO, message=event.message)

@telethon_client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern=r"\/", chats=BOT_CHAT_ID, incoming=False))
async def handler(event):
    global FROM
    # some code here
    FROM.append(CHAT_ID_4)

telethon_client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Decorators are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called. It doesn't make sense for it to be dynamic.

Comment: @Barmar would you suggest some way to update FROM variable?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to do anything. You're not making a copy of the list, so if you append to `FROM`, that will be visible in all the functions.

Comment: yeah, it is visible in catch_messages() functions when i check, but the script can not catch messages from CHAT_ID_4. @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Barmar in the comments, you can't change a decorator after it's been applied to the function. In theory, you could pass assign a list to a variable and use that variable in the decorator, so that mutating it would mutate what the decorator has.

But Telethon's decorators make a copy (for performance reasons) so that won't work.

The easiest thing to do is to check inside the function:

```py
FROM=[CHAT_ID_1, CHAT_ID_2, CHAT_ID_3]

@telethon_client.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing=outgoing, incoming=True))
async def catch_messages(event):
    global FROM
    if event.chat_id not in FROM:  # <- this essentially does the same thing as chats=, except FROM must only contain integer IDs for it to work as intended
        return
    # some codes here
    await telethon_client.send_message(entity=TO, message=event.message)
```

Comment: This is brilliant idea :)